# I work with C# but would like to know how to get something like this to work in VB.Net

Tags: batch-file, service, load, ria

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/smccraw/archive/2009/07/15/a-net-ria-services-data-load-batch-manager.aspx

I used a converter and it worked just fine but the instantiation of the class is looking for an Action(of DomainContextLoadBatch), but the subroutine, Private Sub DataLoadComplete(batch As DomainContextLoadBatch) is not an Action(of DomainContextLoadBatch). What does VB.Net need to make the DataLoadComplete routine work as an Action(of DomainContextLoadBatch) that fires only when all Entities have been loaded into the context. Works fine just the way it looks in C#. Hope that explains it, but I don't know enough about VB.NET to give a better explanation.

```
private DomainContext1 domainContext = new DomainContext1(); 

public MainPage() 
{
    InitializeComponent(); 

    // here
    DomainContextLoadBatch batch = new DomainContextLoadBatch(DataLoadComplete);
    batch.Add(domainContext.Load(domainContext.GetUsersQuery())); 
    batch.Add(domainContext.Load(domainContext.GetUserRolesQuery())); 
    batch.Add(domainContext.Load(domainContext.GetDisciplinesQuery())); 
} 

// and here
private void DataLoadComplete(DomainContextLoadBatch batch)
{     
    if (batch.FailedOperationCount > 0) 
    { 
        // Do Error handling 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        // Fill out the UI with the data 
    } 
}
```

Comment: So, what's your actual question? Did you try to convert this to VB.NET? Did you run into any problems?

Answer (score 1):

There are online-tools for converting C# code to VB.NET and vice-versa. One example is [telerik's code converter](http://converter.telerik.com/).

Comment: Converting is fine, still have syntactic issues though.